# Drive download not working with python code

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to download an exe from google drive with this code but when it downloads it comes out just as a normal txt file and when I run it it says this application can't run on this windows.

[image]

```
import os
import requests
def download(url):
    directory = 'C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming'
    name = 'help.exe'
    file_name = os.path.join(directory, name)
    get_response = requests.get(url)
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(get_response.content)

download('http://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1A2Q3C2VN_8d3AHuNnWX0ZGFmhaeNHNL8&export=download')
```

Comment: What means "it comes out just as a normal text file"? Edit the question to show the beginning of the file. If it is binary you may need a hex viewer to look at it.

Comment: The google drive link is not a link to the file. You are requesting a web page and saving the content of the web page as a file which you named `help.exe`. That's a html file masked as a exe file.